# AzureDevOps Exporting the ProcessTemplate

Tags: azure-devops

We have created a process template on the Enterprise level access on Microsoft AzureDevOps platform. We were looking to export the process template so that it can imported for some other organization. However we do not find an option to do so. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi, friend. Did you try with the solution shared below? Does it could help you achieve what you want?  If yes, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you still facing any issues, feel free to leave commend here :-)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found so far to export inherited processes to other organizations is to use the process-migrator tool that's on GitHub made by Microsoft. There are some wonky things about it that don't totally work but hopefully should be a good start:

https://github.com/Microsoft/process-migrator

You download and install dependencies on the tool then you can run migrate or export/import (I think I usually do export/import).

I think that it works okay as-is except for if you have work item rules that are type CurrentUserIsMemberOfGroup, and picklists don't export correctly, but you'll want to do some testing of the tooling first. I also found out recently that this tooling uses an old SDK/API version (API v4.1) so hopefully it will be updated soon.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure through Azure DevOps UI but there are methods in Azure DevOps Services REST API

[Export Process Template REST API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processadmin/processes/export%20process%20template?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)
[image: export process call description]

[Import Process Template REST API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processadmin/processes/import%20process%20template?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)
[image]

Parameters are pretty straighforward and well explained in MS Documentation.

Comment: This API is not for process templates created via the inherited model.